# How to update the twisted framework

Tags: python, twisted

I can see from the latest 8.2 (almost 1200 lines of code) twisted that I am missing something:
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/words/protocols/jabber/xmlstream.py

My copy (697 lines from 3 years ago) is in:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/twisted/words/protocols/jabber/xmlstream.py

I ran the mac installer found on the website, all looked like it installed fine, but obviously something I am missing:
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads

Can someone tell me how to update twisted properly on my mac?

Comment: I tried with no luck this too: easy_install twisted

Answer (score 17):

Try using `virtualenv` and `pip` (`sudo easy_install virtualenv pip`), which are great ways to avoid the dependency hell that you are experiencing.

With `virtualenv` you can create isolated Python environments, and then using `pip` you can directly install new packages into you `virtualenv`s.

Here is a complete example:

```
#create fresh virtualenv, void of old packages, and install latest Twisted
virtualenv --no-site-packages twisted_env
pip -E twisted_env install -U twisted

#now activate the virtualenv
cd twisted_env
source bin/activate

#test to see you have latest Twisted:
python -c "import twisted; print twisted.__version__"
```

Comment: Following those instructions on OSX 10.7.5, pip squealed "no such option: -E".  I tried cd-ing into the twisted_env and then running "pip install -U twisted".  But, although that did not produce an error, the version of python within the twisted_env failed to import twisted.  The solution was to run "pip install -U twisted" after the line "source bin/active".

Answer (score 1):

You can download that file you mentioned by scrolling to the bottom and click "Download in other formats"

Otherwise just do svn update.

Comment: I'd like to not only update that file but the entire twisted framework

Comment: If I do that would I just remove the existing twisted directory?  Is there any sort of an install process for twisted or is it just as simple as placing the stuff from SVN into a directory?

Comment: It would be best if you just delete and update with SVN. Otherwise just install the file normally.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was hidden away here:
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#WhyamIgettingImportErrorsforTwistedsubpackagesonOSX10.5

Not really clear on exactly how/where to fix the issue though.

After some digging I was able to solve it with this:

From the command prompt type: pico ~/.bash_profile
Add to the top of that file: export PYTHONPATH=~/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/

Save and exit the file and you will finally be running the latest and greatest version twisted. (assuming that you have already downloaded and installed it from the twisted site)